# Error Running Neo4j JDBC Example

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, neo4j

I have some trouble running the example from Neo4j java jdbc.
I am following the instruction from :[GitHub Neo4j-JDBC](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/developer-resources/tree/gh-pages/language-guides/java/jdbc/)
But, when I arrive at :

```
mvn compile exec:java
```

I have a built error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on
>   project neo4j-movies: An exception occured while executing the Java
>   class. null: InvocationTargetException: Unauthorized -> [Help 1]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable auth in your server or provide the credentials to the JDBC driver as connection properties.

```
Properties props = new Properties()
props.setProperty("user","neo4j");
props.setProperty("password","secret");

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/",props);
```